# Discrete Sufficient Statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable from the following distribution
$$f(x;\theta) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} \theta & , & x = -1 \\ (1 - \theta)^2\theta^x & , & x = 0,1,2,\ldots\end{array}\right.$$

where $0\leq \theta \leq 1$. Find a sufficient statistic for the parameter $\theta$.

**Answer**: I started by creating an indicator function, where
$$I_1(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & x = -1 \\ 0 & , & {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Then,
$$f(x;\theta) = \theta^{I_1(x)}(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x = \theta^{I_1(x) + x}(1 - \theta)^2\cdot 1$$

By the Factorization Theorem: $k_1(x;\theta) = \theta^{I_1(x) + x}(1 - \theta)^2$ and $k_2(x) = 1$.

Therefore, $T(x) = I_1(x) + x$ is a sufficient statistic.

Have I proceeded in the correct manner? What role does $0\leq \theta \leq 1$ play here?

Answer (score 3):

The representation
$$f(x;\theta) = \theta^{I_1(x)}(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x$$
is incorrect, even when restricted to $x\in\{-1,0,1,\ldots\}$. It would for instance lead to
$$f(-1;\theta) = \theta^{I_1(-1)}(1 - \theta)^2\theta^{-1}=(1-\theta)^2$$
(Notice the confusing impact of the notation $I_1(x)$ with $I_1(-1)=1$ and $I_1(1)=0$...)

Since the part $(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x$ should *only* appear when $x\ge 0$, it need be replaced with $1$ when $x=-1$, i.e., when $I_1(x)=1$, which is the case for
$$\{(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x\}^{1-I_1(x)}$$

Comment: So should I introduce a second indicator function for $(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x$?

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can restrict the $x$ in $(1−\theta)^2\theta^x$ to only be used if $x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$

Comment: So in this case:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x;\theta) & = & \theta^{I_1(x)}\Big[(1 - \theta)^2\theta^x\Big]^{1 - I_1(x)} \\
& = & \theta^{I_1(x)}(1 - \theta)^{2(1 - I_1(x))}\theta^{x(1 - I_1(x))} \\
& = & \theta^{I_1(x) + x(1 - I_1(x))}(1 - \theta)^{2(1 - I_1(x))}\cdot 1 \\
& = & k_1(S(X);\theta)k_2(X).
\end{eqnarray*}

So by the factorization theorem $T(X) = (I_1(x) + x(1 - I_1(x)), 2(1 - I_1(x)))$ is a sufficient statistic of $\theta$.

Comment: I would think the homework/problem requires a sufficient statistic for an $n$ sample rather than for a single observation, $x$, since $x$ itself is obviously sufficient. Note also that $I_1(x)+(1-I_1(x))x=|x|$.

Comment: The question is actually for a single observation $X$. I appreciate the help.

Comment: In that case, $X$ itself is sufficient.